# Convert C++ callback function to Delphi

Tags: c++, function, delphi

I need help in translating this C++ header into Delphi.

It's a callback function prototype, and some inline functions (I have no clear idea why they are there, since it seems they are not used).

***Source .h code:***

```
// This file defines 'myStreamWriter_t' a function pointer type.
// The user of the C API need to specify a callback of above type which
// will be called on xxx_print(...) with the formatted data.
// For C++ API, a default callback is specified which writes data to
// the stream specified in xxx::print

typedef int(*myStreamWriter_t)(const char* p1,
                                     int p2,
                                     void *p3);
```

The above It's quite easy: it should translate, in *Delphi*, as follows:

```
type
   myStreamWriter_t = function(const p1:Pchar; 
                                     p2:integer;
                                     p3:pointer):integer;
```

Now, there are other things that I don't know how to translate:

***Souce .h code:***

```
#include <ostream>

namespace ns1 {
namespace ns2 {

inline int OstreamWriter(const char *p1, int p2, void *p3);

struct StreamProxyOstream {

static int writeToStream(const char* p1, int p2, void *p3);
    // Format, to the specified 'p3' stream, which must be a pointer to a
    // 'std::ostream', the specified 'p2' bytes length of the specified 'p1' data.
};


inline
int StreamProxyOstream::writeToStream(const char *p1,
                                      int         p2,
                                      void       *p3)
{
    reinterpret_cast<std::ostream*>(p3)->write(p1, p2);
    return 0;
}

inline
int OstreamWriter(const char *p1, int p2, void *p3)
{
    return StreamProxyOstream::writeToStream(p1, p2, p3);
}

}  // close namespace ns2
}  // close namespace ns1
```

...how to translate in Delphi the above??

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your translation is not correct. It should probably be:

```pascal
type
  myStreamWriter_t = function(p1: PAnsiChar; p2: Integer; p3: Pointer): Integer cdecl;
```

Note that there is no Delphi equivalent for `const char *x` (non-const pointer to const chars), so just use PAnsiChar. In any Delphi from 2009 on, PChar is PWideChar, and that is not the equivalent to `char *`.

`const x: PAnsiChar` is the equivalent of `char * const x`, meaning the **pointer** is const, not the char(s) it points to.

And it is very likely that your calling convention is wrong.

Similarly, you should translate the other functions. But note that a function (method) on a struct may be called differently, i.e. using a proprietary Microsoft convention for methods (__thiscall). There is no Delphi equivalent for it.

But probably you can't call such methods without getting into compatibility trouble anyway. **You can mimic the behaviour of these classes/structs**, but you **will not be able to make them binary compatible in Delphi**, unless you jump through several hoops and/or use assembler.

More info on my website:

- [Pitfalls of converting](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html)
- [Using C++ objects in Delphi](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html)
- [DLL dos and don'ts](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-dlls.html)
- [Using C object files in Delphi](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cobjs.html)

If you want to **mimic** the behaviour, you can do something like:

```pascal
 OstreamWriter(p1: AnsiChar; p2: Integer; p3: Pointer): Integer; // no need for binary compatibility, so you can omit cdecl
 begin
   TStream(p3).Write(p1^, StrLen(p1) + 1);
   TStream(p3).Write(p2, SizeOf(p2));
 end;
```

But you will have to rewrite the entire C++ code. This is not something simple, if you already have problems with the code above.